# With Python, SQLite and HTML, how do i read from a database and print to page?

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, types

I am a beginner in SQLite, so please bear with me if what i'm about to ask seems silly.

I currently have a database called "Status", with two columns "stamp" and "messages". "messages" contains a text, and "stamp" contains a time stamp.

I would like to read the last 10 entries of this database, and display them to a HTML page.

The code I am using to read from database is:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def readStatus(self):
    con = lite.connect('static/database/Status.db')
    output = ""
    with con:    

        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT messages FROM Status ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 5")
        print "The Status database now contains:"

        for row in cur:
            print row
            output = output + row

    return output
```

The code I am using to print the messages onto an HTML page is

```
@cherrypy.expose
def homepage(self):
    """Display the home page showing status update
    """
    page = get_file(staticfolder+"/html/homePage.html")
    page = page.replace("$STATUS", self.readStatus())
    return page
```

However, I am getting this error message:

```
File "proj1base.py", line 133, in homepage
    page = page.replace("$STATUS", self.readStatus())
  File "proj1base.py", line 305, in readStatus
    output = output + row
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means, I assume it is saying that the type between 'output' and 'row' is mismatching. However, what 'row' should be reading is 'messages' column of database 'status', which is a string, and 'output' is also a string. So I don't know what's happening and is wondering if anyone could help?

Comment: While it is not your problem, the convention in Python for variable and function names is words lowercase separated by underscores, rather than camel case. (see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *you're* querying for only one column, SQLite *also* supports querying for multiple columns. However, for consistency, Python *always* puts them in a tuple. You probably want to get the first element of the tuple, which *will* be a string:

```
output = output + row[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, that really does help clarify thing a bit.